# Shopify API for Customer Login

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api

I am creating a mobile app using Xamarin Forms. So, in that app, I have a screen on which the Shopify customers have to login using their username and password. So, my question is that which API or mechanism should I use to login customers?

Comment: https://shopify.dev/api/usage/authentication

Answer (score 0):

You can read this one as i find this myself really helpful : https://shopify.dev/api/admin/graphql/reference/customers/customer